# How to pass const inside useState in react

Tags: reactjs, use-state, react-functional-component

I have a code in which I need to pass a const inside the useState can someone help??

The below code is in class constructor I want to convert that into functional component

Class Component:

```
     constructor(props){
     super(props);
     const {id, name, email} = props.location.state.contact;
     this.state={
                 id,
                 name,
                 email
                 }
```

How to do this above in functional component?

Comment: 1. I would suggest using functional component. As a beginner, you will have less overhead. 
Can you provide your full class component code?

Comment: import {useState} from 'react' and then const [name,setName] = useState("")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get props by destructuring inside the function component without using `useState`

```
import React from 'react';

function Test(props) {

    // destructuring
    const { id, name, email } = props;
    return (
        <div>
          ...
        </div>
    )
}

export default Test;
```

But if you want to use `useState`:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

function Test(props) {

    const [state, setState] = useState(props.location.state.contact);
    return (
        <div>
          ...
        </div>
    )
}

export default Test;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a default value for the use state hook. Just pass the props.

```
function Component(props) {
  const {location:{ state: { contact: { id, name, email } } }} = props;
  const [state, setState] = useState({id, name, email});
}
```

If you want to reset the state on the prop changes, set a `useEffect` hook with the respective props in the dependency array, and set the state with the new values.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can do the following

```js
function Component(props) {
  const [state, setState] = useState(props.location.state.contact);
  // state will have id, name, and email
  return <></>
}
```

Read more about usage of hooks [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use it as `function component` like this

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';

function myComponent(props) {

    const {id, name, email} = props.location.state.contact;
    const [stateValue, setStateValue] = useState({id, name, email});

    return (
       ....
    )
}

export default myComponent;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const Component = (props) => {
  const [state, setState] = useState(props.location.state.contact);

  
  return <div></div>;
};

export default Component;
```

code sandbox with an example:
https://codesandbox.io/s/upbeat-framework-li4rb?file=/src/Component.js